# android radiusnetwork iBeaconLibrary didDetermineStateForRegion when is called?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I cannot understand the use of didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) in ibeaconSevice library.

I have a service that runs in background mode, when I see a beacon for the first time both 
didEnterRegion(Region region) and didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) are called. Then the scan is stopped. In the next Scan no callback is performed even though I am still in the same region.
Please, could you help?

```
iBeaconManager.setBackgroundMode(this, true);
iBeaconManager.setBackgroundMode(this, true);    
     iBeaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
      @Override
      public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
      Log.d(ConstantsDecoder.LOGTAG, "I just saw an iBeacon for the first time!"); 
}


@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
                Log.d(ConstantsDecoder.LOGTAG, "I have just switched from   seeing/not seeing iBeacons: "+state); 

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These methods only get called *once* for each state change.  So it works like this:

1. An iBeacon becomes visible to the device.
2. `didEnterRegion` and `didDetermineStateForRegion` get called.
3. No more calls are made to the above methods while the iBeacon is visible to the device.
4. The iBeacon is no longer visible to the device.
5. `didExitRegion` and `didDetermineStateForRegion` get called.
6. No more calls are made to the above methods while the iBeacon is not visible to the device.
7. Go to step 1.

If you want to get a call once per second with a list of all iBeacons that are being seen, use the Ranging Example Code [here.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/samples.html)

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I think it will be useful and more similar to iOS behaviour to receive didDetermineStateForRegion  after every scan to confirm that you are still in beacon region and generate action.

Comment: Kinda agree with Sfavilla, that would be a useful feature. On a sidenote, why even have didDetermineStateForRegion, if didEnterRegion and didExitRegion literally fulfill that function?

Comment: While it is true you could do without the method, the reason it exists is to ease developing cross-platform apps that rely on the equivalent method on iOS.  For that reason, I agree that it is a good idea to make it function as similarly as possible.  That said, I do not believe that the method gets called on iOS with each scan.  It gets called on each state change or on specific events like display illumination (when so configured.)